# In SlateJS, how to change focus to specific editor when multiple editors are present?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, focus, slatejs

I have multiple SlateJS editors in my app, representing individual pages. When I add a new page, I want the focus to be changed to the editor within that page.

I have no idea how to do this! I've checked in the docs and there are `onFocus` and `onBlur` hook plugins, but this is for reacting to focus changes. On the [slack community snippets](https://github.com/objectlegal/slate-snippets) there is this:

```
// Moving cursor to the end of the document
ReactEditor.focus(editor);
Transforms.select(editor, Editor.end(editor, []));
```

But I can't get this to work either. This is a cut-down version of my code:

**Root element**

```
<div>
    {pages.map((pageID: number) => (
        <Page onChange={updatePage(pageID)}/>
    ))}
</div>
```

**Page Element**

```
<div>
    <Input onChange={onChange}/>
</div>
```

And then the `<Input/>` element renders the `Slate` and `Editable` components from `slate-react`.

I've tried to RTFM but I legitiamtely cannot find anything about managing focus aside from that [plugins page](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/slate-react/plugins#onfocus).

I've tried adding a `focusOnRender` boolean prop, and using it a hook on the `Input` element:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (focusOnRender)
        ReactEditor.focus(editor);
}, [focusOnRender]);
```

But this just doesn't work for me.

I've found [this page in the docs](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/guides/commands-and-queries#expressiveness-is-key) which describes an `editor.focus()` function, but when I try this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: editor.focus is not a function
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this helps, but I've had some success with wrapping `ReactEditor.focus(editor)` inside a setTimeout(). I do this *outside* of the component tree (e.g., instead of puttting it in `useEffect` of a component, try putting it in an event handler, or calling it from console).

FYI, the `editor.focus()` docs you're referencing are on Slate 0.47, and the API has changed significantly in 0.50+ (if you're using the `Transforms.select` or `ReactEditor.focus` API, you're on version 0.50+)

Answer (score 1):

Using slate `v0.81.0` this is what worked for me:

```js
useMemo(() => {
   Transforms.select(editor, { offset: 0, path: [0, 0] });
}, []);
```